Compress and encryption the files to cloud vm using adf
I have a requirement which is to be created in AZURE DATA FACTORY.
In ADLS I have a .dat & .aud files I need to compress and copy them to cloud vm. Can we do that ? Please let me KNOW.
I have tried to zip only the files but in folder there two formate type of files are there which needs to be .zip and copy to cloud vm after copying the. Zip files I need to encrypt the files with .aes and move to other folder within the cloud vm.

You can use Binary datasets to achieve your requirement.
Create binary dataset with ADLS linked service for the source ADLS and for your target VM, you need to use Self-hosted Integration runtime. You need to install Self-hosted IR in your VM to make a connection with ADF. You can follow this blog by @Sneha raina to know about it.
After installing it in the VM, create File system linked service with IR as Self-hosted. Then, create binary dataset for this linked service.
Add both source and target binary datasets to a copy activity in ADF pipeline. In the source binary dataset, make sure the Compression is set to None and provide your folder path which contains the required files.

In the target binary dataset, set the Compression type to ZipDeflate (.zip) and give your target file name. Here, for sample I have used ADLS as target. In your case, you need to use File system linked service which is created with Self-hosted IR.

Debug the pipeline and the required .zip file will be generated in your target location and it will contain the input files.
Zip file after downloading:

